# Hive transform with Python library in a folder

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I'd like to run a Python script in my TRANSFORM that uses an external library, which I'm unable to install in the cluster.

For tests outside Hive, I could just copy the folder with the main files to my home directory, where the script is, and run from there, with an "import "

For Hive, I don't know how to use this library. I tried importing the files one by one with `ADD FILE` and also tried zipping and using `ADD ARCHIVE`, but I keep getting the message

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 20003 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask. An error occurred when trying to close the Operator running your custom script.
```

Any suggestions on how I can adapt my script to use these files?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the log dump. That would be more helpful to troubleshoot. I came across the same problem and it resulted in the transformer library i wrote was referring to non-existent classes.

I din't had enough reputation to put this in as comment.